# Why am I unable to convert datatype to return blank cells for values of 0 or NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently trying to return '' for values that are either NULL or 0, but am unable to do so:

```
select isnull(cast(sec_column as varchar(10)),'')
```

sec_column is `Numeric`

The above produces the follow sql error:

> "Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar"

Additionally, I have tried something simpler along the lines of an `ISNULL` to achieve this, but to no avail:

```
select isnull(sec_column,'')
```

I assume that I should be able to cast as a string value and return blank. Any insight into this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the data type of `sec_column`?

Comment: sec_column is numeric

Comment: if you are using sql2012+, you can use Try_Parse or Try_Convert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this can help.

Assuming sec_column is a numeric, and you want to show zeros and nulls as ""

```
select isnull(cast(nullif(sec_column,0) as varchar(10)),'')
```

Example

```
Declare @YourTable Table (sec_column int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (1)
,(null)
,(25)
,(0)

select *
      ,AsString = isnull(cast(nullif(sec_column,0) as varchar(10)),'')
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
sec_column  AsString
1           1
NULL    
25          25
0
```

Comment: @andrewbradley Happy it helped.  SqlZim raised a valid point.  I'm assuming varchar(10) was sufficient.  Depending on your values, you may have to up it to say varchar(25)

Comment: Thanks John. I ended up incorporating both of your suggestions, as character type size in fact needed to be higher than 10 (in this case, 25 was sufficient as you suggested)

Comment: @andrewbradley Happy it helped.

Answer (score 2):

That error for the given code would indicate you need a larger `varchar()`:

```
select isnull(cast(sec_column as varchar(39)),'')
```

---

```
declare @val numeric(38,2) = '123456789123456789123456789123456789.12'

/* works fine */
select convert(varchar(39),@val)

select convert(varchar(10),@val)
/* Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar. */
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GMYUUN51608

Comment: awe come on where's the link to aaron's post about never defining a character type w/o size?  but I guess size was defined, it was just too small.

Comment: @xQbert But OP did specify a size, it is specified as 10.